# dd is working with bs argument but gives IO error without

Tags: hard-disk, dd

I have a HDD 4TB WD 40EFRX (red series) and try to check the health of that disc. Actually, I erased all partitions and the table via gparted and build a new table + ex4 partition. Subsequently, I wanted to overwrite all the data with zeroes in order to get rid of old data. However, I figured out that using

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb status=progress
```

result in an I/O error right at the beginning:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb status=progress
474558976 bytes (475 MB, 453 MiB) copied, 38.0445 s, 12.5 MB/s
dd: writing to '/dev/sdb': Input/output error
927977+0 records in
927976+0 records out
475123712 bytes (475 MB, 453 MiB) copied, 46.6914 s, 10.2 MB/s
```

while adding the option bs=64MB (cache of that HDD is 64 MB) the command works really fine. However, I guess based on the IO error the HDD is somehow dead or can I do other workarounds too? By the way, I have the HDD via SATA/USB connected to my laptop.

Comment: Does the error always occur at the same address?

Comment: @HaukeLaging, hmm, you're right, I didn't read the sample output very well, it seems.

Comment: I do also wonder what happens if the drive is plugged directly to a computer. With a USB adapter in the middle, it could be another source of issues.

Comment: @ilkkachu you are right but I have no other possibility right now. My desktop PC is 500 km far away.

HaukeLaging I will check it out. Right now another HDD (same type) is running but the error occured always very rapidly (lets say after a few seconds so I guess it could be the same sample always).

Comment: @HaukeLaging, the error does not appear on the same sample

Comment: Use `smartctl -a /dev/sdb` to see what the disk thinks of its own fail state, and then run a `-t short` or `-t long` test too.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick smartctl shows errors:

`# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       60%      2387         907736`

as well as the second and third entry:
`# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       60%      2387         907960`

It is interesting that the position is always different LBA_of_first_error

Comment: Hi all, during the night I wrote zeros to all sectors using `bb if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb status=progress conv=sync bs=4096` which worked fine. I did it based on reparing sectors (https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/smartctl-read-failure%3B-is-my-hd-failing-920243/). However, the smart check still does not work. So I will sent the HDD back. The only thing that is interesting is that `dd` without the `bs` does not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

I admit that I have neither encountered nor heard about the following problem but on the other hand I am not an harddisk failure expert... :-)

The pure amount of I/O operations might somehow cause the problem. Between the two kinds of `dd` calls is the factor 128,000 in the number of read and write operations. I do not know whether the Linux block layer somehow reorders direct accesses to a block device. If it does then this factor would be lower.

You may try smaller block sizes. `bs=512KB` would be a reduction by a factor of 1024. Perhaps you find that even a block size much smaller that the cache size makes the problem disappear.

Comment: If I do not set a block size, which one is used as default one? As I said, if I put an blocksize such as bs=64MB, dd works fine (at least for the first hour). If I do use bb without the block size specification, it fails - always but only with one of the two HDD. 

So, how could I be sure the HDD is still okay.? Right now, I am using 512KB and it works fine till now too. Thanks for your reply. By the way is it normal that the transfer (write) rate starts with 130MB/s and falls to 20 MB/s and goes back to 75 MB/s.

Comment: @Tobi As ilkkachu alreasy wrote: The default block size of `dd` is 512 bytes.

Comment: @Tobi I am not familiar with the progression of transfer speeds but I assume that in the beginning the empty disk cache helps a lot. When the cache is filled up then it is probably partly flushed which stalls the I/O operations which arrive during that time. After the partly flush an equilibrium is reached, I guess, which is between the highest and lowest transfer rate.

Comment: sorry, I did not see that ilkkachu said that the default value is 512 bytes. The speedup explanation seems to be fine for me. Thanks for the reply. I checked the disc with smartclt and it seems there is a problem (comment above)